# Play framework with Gzip not working

Tags: scala, playframework, gzip, playframework-2.2

As you know, play! [introduced Gzip encoding](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/GzipEncoding) in 2.2.0 version.
Unfortunately, after updating project and updating play, it doesn't work.

```
[error] ...\app\Global.scala:4: object filters is not a member of package play
[error] import play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter
[error]             ^
[error] ...\app\Global.scala:8: not found: type GzipFilter
[error] object Global extends WithFilters(new GzipFilter) with GlobalSettings {
[error]                                       ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

It doesn't work even if I create project form console `play new TEST`.

However in `C:\play-2.2.0\framework\src\play-filters-helpers\src\main\scala\play\filters\gzip` I have both `Gzip.scala` and `GzipFilter.scala`.

My `\app\Global.scala` looks like that:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Global extends WithFilters(new GzipFilter) with GlobalSettings {
    override def onStart(app: Application) {
        Logger.info("Application has started")
    }

    override def onStop(app: Application) {
        Logger.info("Application shutdown")
    }

    override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = Future { InternalServerError("{}") }
    override def onBadRequest(request: RequestHeader, error: String) = Future { BadRequest("{}") }
    override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader) = Future { NotFound("{}") }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone made that working?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In **Build.scala**, just add "filters" to your app dependencies

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  jdbc, cache, filters, ...
)
```

or, if you are doing it with **build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc, cache, filters, ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain it and tell how to avoid mistakes like that in the future?

Comment: There is not much you can do to avoid a missing dependency. But the error message `XXX is not a member of package YYY` is always a pretty good indicator that a package is missing (as long as YYY is none of your own packages).

Comment: ... and if you've created your Play project by hand, the `filters` `ModuleID` (dependency) exists in `play.Project` so make sure to include `import play.Project._` in your build file.

Comment: Perfect. It didn't show up straight away for me so I ran "play clean", "play eclipse" and then refreshed my project in Eclispe.